# How to Safely Sterilize Europa?

Tags: science-fiction, space, diseases

In *The Lost Fleet* series, it's established that a genetically-engineered disease was accidentally released on Europa, which wiped out all the colonists present.  By the time of the series, an insane amount of effort is put into making sure that that disease NEVER escapes.  I'm curious about what it would take in order to sterilize a Europa-like planet from orbit without risking sending such a disease flying into - or out of - orbit.

Assume a Europa-like planet.  It's a fairly small ice ball, escape velocity low enough that any high-energy bombardment, such as with relativistic projectiles, risks sending contaminated debris off to who-knows-where (never mind that the odds of anything surviving the trip to anywhere habitable are close to nil.)  The disease itself is a virus or bacteria that can survive vacuum indefinitely, but which, like everything else, cannot survive being boiled.  (By which I mean temperatures exceeding 100 degrees Celsius for any significant length of time.)

At your disposal is a substantial budget and technology on par with or better than what we see in, say, *The Expanse*.  You have a substantial space-based infrastructure at your disposal.  How would you go about making reasonably sure that the pathogen was well and truly *gone*?

Comment: (a) Questions about third-party worlds (especially commercial third-party worlds) are verboten. You can use them as an example while building your own world (here are my world's rules, now how can I have something like a light sabre in it?), but you can't modify them directly. It's playing with canon, and that's better suited to [scifi.se]. (b) Without a complete description of the infection, this is factually impossible to answer. It would help knowing how much of Europa needs to survive, too. Without that detail, this is too story-based.

Comment: @JBH I'll modify the question, then.

Comment: I retracted my close vote, but I think you need to pick one: a virus or a bacteria. Different solutions work for each and you won't be able to pick just one best answer, which is a requirement.

Comment: what's wrong with radiation?

Comment: Turn off whatever shielding you must have already had in place to protect colonists from the steady hard proton-'sleet' prevalent in the area.  Let nature take its course.

Comment: Why is your boiling point of water 100C in space? That's at sea level, in the vacuum of space it will already be well past the boiling point. Do you just want to set 100C as an arbitrary "too hot to survive"? Or do you want the disease to die whenever the water inside boils?

Comment: @PoorCorrelation I figured it would be the arbitrary 'too hot to survive', since I'm not sure if it's the temperature or the boiling that kills pathogens on Earth.

Comment: Do you want Europa to be useful afterwards? Heating all its water to 100C will cause much of it to be lost into space.

Comment: @JohnDallman It doesn't need to be useful afterwards.  After all, the place is already useless, less than useless, since it's a drain on resources to quarantine it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the way to kill the bacteria/virus is to boil it, then you will need to boil Europa. There is one caveat to the problem (and indeed that might even make the problem go away): the vapour from the boiling oceans cannot be allowed to escape, since there is a slim possibility to carry the infectious material into space.

Step one: surround Europa with a giant "bubble". This bubble needs to be transparent to energy coming through, and strong enough to contain the pressures generated inside and against being pierced by external forces. A bubble of synthetic diamond should do. At the scale we are talking about, it will be essentially like a giant soap bubble, which is why we need a strong material. Given the enclosure of the moon, you may simply end it there - bacteria and virii are not going to escape on their own.

Step two: establish a laser in the solar photosphere. The photosphere is an energetic plasma, and sending a laser through the plasma should create a channel of even more highly ionized gas which undergoes a "population inversion" and radically amplifies the origin laser. By having a series of mirrors orbiting the Sun at close range, the beam can travel around the photosphere multiple times, generating immense amounts of energy. At the proper time, one of the mirrors is either removed or its properties changed to allow the beam to pass though. A further system of mirrors and fresnel lenses transfer the energy across the Solar System to focus on Europa, and by carefully modulating the energy, the moon can be slowly heated and brought to a boil. The steam will condense on the side of the bubble away from the beam, and the orbital path of the moon will likely bring the masses of ice into the field of the laser, causing it to detach from the bubble and fall back into the Europan ocean.

The amount of energy to gradually boil Europa is going to be pretty huge, but it can be spread out over any arbitrary amount of time. This ensures the bubble doesn't "pop", and allows condensation to cool the steam, with the masses of distilled water ice falling into the ocean and ensuring mixing of the waters and the application of laser heat and energy to all of the waters over time.

The massive energy of the beam can also be sold commercially to distant objects (even as far out as the Oort cloud), so the project can pay for itself.

Answer (score -2):

> The disease itself is a virus or bacteria that can survive vacuum indefinitely, but which, like everything else, **cannot survive being boiled. (By which I mean temperatures exceeding 100 degrees Celsius for any significant length of time.)**

Boil Europa then. She's really small, just 3.09×10<sup>7</sup> km<sup>2</sup>. If you have drones that can scorch a square click each (with space thermite/napalm) you just need thirty million drones. Seems doable for a space faring civilization.

Comment: Europa’s ocean is believed to be 60 miles of water under 15 miles of ice. Drones boiling the surface will have no effect at all on life in the ocean. And the amount of time and energy required for a drone to boil to the bottom of the ocean are completely prohibitive.